# SharePoint Whitespace in Table Rows

Tags: sharepoint, whitespace, rows

I am doing some tidy up work on company SP. Many of the pages have tables with hyperlinks to various documents but some pages do not have a table, just the links, and it can get messy when trying to edit the links or whatever. For the ones that do not have tables I am adding a table and putting the hyperlinks in the rows.

I am getting a problem where when I check the changes in the spaces between the rows increases dramatically and I have tried replicating sizing of existing tables that do not have large gaps in rows, and have checked the code for br tags etc.

I tried viewing the page in chrome and it looks fine so I reckon there is something with IE that is causing this. Don't know what though.

Any help on this would be most welcome.

Andrew

Update: In IE (on IE8) I went into developer tools and changed document mode to IE8 standards, was set at 7 and this seemed to fix the whitespace problem, but only on that page. Also the menu seems to jump up and down when you hover over it, but as I said only for that one page. the menu also does the same thing in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Links web part?
If not, please give a try for it.